# How to apply a Service Override implicitly (inline, when resolving) in Castle Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, overriding

Consider the form using additional parameters to resolved components that "works". Note that it is *okay* if the root is Resolved here.

```
var c1a = container.Resolve<IC1>(new { v = "a" });
var c1b = container.Resolve<IC1>(new { v = "b" });
// Takes two different objects, of the same interface
var root = container.Resolve<C2>(new { c1a = c1a, c2a = c2a });
```

However I don't like it because 1. neither `c1a` not `c2a` will be "auto released" and 2. it feels too manual.

```
container.Release(c2);
container.Release(c1a);
container.Release(c1b);
```

What I would like to do is something like the following (which is invalid of course) that uses an *implicit* service override - note that there is only one direct Resolve and the objects should be created by CW internally.

```
var root = container.Resolve<C2>(new {
   c1a = InlineOverride.For<IC1>.With(new { v = "a" }),
   c2a = InlineOverride.For<IC1>.With(new { v = "a" })
});
container.Release(root); // Just one root
```

I have a feeling I am just missing the concept / application of [Service Overrides](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx) which appear to only be supported *explicitly during registration* of the dependent (C2) component.

Answer (score 0):

so just one way that i have handled something close to this, not sure if it will help out.

```
public class Tinker
{
    public interface ISomethingWithChar
    {
        char V { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomethingWithChar:ISomethingWithChar
    {
        public char V { get; set; }
    }

    public interface INeedTwoSomethingWithChars
    {
        ISomethingWithChar C1A { get; set; }
        ISomethingWithChar C2A { get; set; }
    }

    public class NeedTwoSomethingWithChars:INeedTwoSomethingWithChars
    {
        public ISomethingWithChar C1A { get; set; }
        public ISomethingWithChar C2A { get; set; }
    }

    public class Installers:IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
            Component
                .For<ISomethingWithChar>()
                .ImplementedBy<SomethingWithChar>()
                .Named("CharOne")
                .DynamicParameters((k,d) =>
                {
                    d["V"] = container.Resolve<IArgs>().CharOne;
                }),
            Component
                .For<ISomethingWithChar>()
                .ImplementedBy<SomethingWithChar>()
                .Named("CharTwo")
                .DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
                {
                    d["V"] = container.Resolve<IArgs>().CharTwo;
                }),
            Component
                .For<INeedTwoSomethingWithChars>()
                .ImplementedBy<NeedTwoSomethingWithChars>()
                .DependsOn(Parameter.ForKey("C1A").Eq("${CharOne}"), Parameter.ForKey("C2A").Eq("${CharTwo}")));
        }
    }


    public static void DoSomething(IArgs args)
    {
        using (var container = BootstrapContainer(args))
        {
            var needTwo = container.Resolve<INeedTwoSomethingWithChars>();
            Console.WriteLine("One: {0} and Two: {1}", needTwo.C1A.V, needTwo.C2A.V);
        }
    }

    private static IWindsorContainer BootstrapContainer(IArgs args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component
            .For<IArgs>()
            .Instance(args));

        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

        return container;
    }
}
```